# Add child to E4X with my variable

Tags: javascript, mirth, e4x

This is using Mirth Connect which uses E4x and js.

Basically I have a variable that I want to populate the XML with.

```
var memberid = "1234";
var fieldsxml = new XML(<fieldvaluelist></fieldvaluelist>);
fieldsxml.field += <fieldvalue templatefieldid="446" value=@memberid/> //memberID
```

But its giving an error on the 3rd line:  (I also tried just memberid without quotes)

> DETAILS:  TypeError: Open quote is expected for attribute "value"
>   associated with an  element type  "fieldvalue".

It works if the third line is this:

```
fieldsxml.field += <fieldvalue templatefieldid="446" value="memberid"/>
```

But that just adds the literal string "memberid" .  I actually want value="1234" instead.

How can I do this?

Edit:  The final XML should look like this.

```
<fieldvaluelist><fieldvalue templatefieldid="446" value="1234"/></fieldvaluelist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Instead of using @memberId, use {memberId}:

```
fieldsxml.field += <fieldvalue templatefieldid="446" value={memberid}/>;
```